# Can't get App.config settings to persist

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, app-config

**Problem: Value set by user on initial startup won't stay in App.config xml**

**Desired functionality: Value set by user to stay stored in App.config unless changed by user**

I'm trying to make it so that the first time the application is run by the user they set a folder where the files they make with the program will be saved. I want to store that string in the App.config so that it only has to be set once. As of right now it will set it and hold it in memory but if the program closes the value is lost. I thought calling the .save() method would fix it but it has not.
On form opening:

```
if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SaveFilePath"] == null)
{
    FolderBrowserDialog fbd1 = new FolderBrowserDialog();
    fbd1.RootFolder = Environment.SpecialFolder.MyComputer;
    fbd1.Description = "Select a folder to save to:";
    fbd1.ShowNewFolderButton = true;

    if (fbd1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
        config.AppSettings.Settings.Add("SaveFilePath", fbd1.SelectedPath);
        config.Save();

        ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");
    }
}
```

Comment: App.Config isn't intended to be a persistent storage solution.  You should look into persisting these options another way, perhaps a settings.json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One should be using the application settings file (see it in the properties pages of the project) to store and retrieve user settings.

See [Using Settings in C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869(v=vs.80).aspx). *The page shows VS 2005, but it is still viable into projects using VS 2017*

---

- [Settings Page, Project Designer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(ApplicationSettingsOverview);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.6.2)&rd=true)
- [.Net Pearls C# Settings](https://www.dotnetperls.com/settings)

[image]

Comment: This sounds great. I followed the article and created a new setting to hold the path. I replaced the if condition to check `Properties.Settings.Default.defaultFilePath == "C:\\"` but it does not work. I’m getting information messages at runtime that say “Could not find the schema information for the element ‘userSettings’”. What needs to be configured that I missed?

Comment: @BrettMinster something else is happening which is not apparent. I have used the user project settings in many projects. I suggest you create a console application to try it there. If it works, something in the main is having a problem. If not, then you can post the issue back here to SO with the example. Remember that everytime you build, the user settings are overwritten to the `install` state and not kept.

Comment: The issue I was having was elsewhere in the code. It now stores the value properly and can be changed by the user if desired. I still haven't been able to resolve the messages that show up in the error console, but it works properly and they are not actual errors or warnings. Thanks!